# how to print for loop results in a upper triangular matrix in R

Tags: arrays, string, r, algorithm, excel

The script in R as follow.

```
   for (i in 1:(ncol(K)-1)) #ncol=7,K is dataset
     for (j in i:ncol(K)){
     print(mi.empirical(rbind(K[, i],K[,j])))
     }
```

output is given as

```
[1] 0
 [1] 0.1412579
 [1] 0.4597332
 [1] 0.382798
 [1] 0.1162086
 [1] 0.3379114
 [1] 0.4848073
 [1] 0
 [1] 0.3103481
 [1] 0.1556235
 [1] 0.02243661
 [1] 0.123117
 [1] 0.2290079
 [1] 0
 [1] 0.1460452
 [1] 0.3638203
 [1] 0.2569532
 [1] 0.1117262
 [1] 0
 [1] 0.1981758
 [1] 0.05325737
 [1] 0.03590259
 [1] 0
 [1] 0.1380921
 [1] 0.3007399
 [1] 0
 [1] 0.1032283
```

Can someone tell me how to print this results in a upper triangular matrix  (7 x 7 matrix)? 
All zeros (0) are in Diagonal. Please help me.

Thank u in advance.

Comment: You mean you want the output formatted to look like a matrix, or you only want the entries in the upper triangle?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print the results as a matrix, then, using this dummy data

```
n <- 7
vec <- seq_len((0.5 * (n * (n-1)) + n)) ## dummy data, *inc* diagonal
```

which will play the role of the cumulated output from `mi.empirical()`, create an empty matrix

```
mat <- matrix(ncol = 7, nrow = 7)
```

Then index the upper triangle of `mat` using `upper.tri(mat, diag = TRUE)` and assign the cumulated results to it

```
mat[upper.tri(mat, diag = TRUE)] <- vec

> mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    1    2    4    7   11   16   22
[2,]   NA    3    5    8   12   17   23
[3,]   NA   NA    6    9   13   18   24
[4,]   NA   NA   NA   10   14   19   25
[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   15   20   26
[6,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   21   27
[7,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   28
```

You are going to need to put all the outputs from `mi.empirical()` into a single vector though, rather than printing each intermediary result.

Answer (score 0):

`upper.tri` is probably what you're looking for:

```
#Generating a reproducible 7x7 matrix:
set.seed(1)
m <- matrix(rexp(49, rate=.1), ncol=7)
diag(m) <- rep(0, ncol(m))

#The calculation you're looking for:
m[upper.tri(m, diag = FALSE)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are anyway looping over the indices, you may as well fill up a matrix while you are doing it.

For example:

```
answers <- matrix(NA_character_, nrow=ncol(K) - 1, ncol=ncol(K))

for (i in 1:(ncol(K)-1))
  for (j in i:ncol(K)){
  answers[i, j] <- mi.empirical(rbind(K[, i],K[,j]))
}

print(answers)
```

Comment: Thanks all for quick response. Really helpful ur answers.